# Puppeteer <a> tag click

Tags: c#, click, puppeteer

First of all, good work everyone. I'm pulling data from a site using Puppeteer, after the data extraction process is finished, I want to move on to the next page. For this, there is an  tag as below.

```
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="empTable" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="empTable_next">Next</a>
```

The codes I'm trying to click are as follows

```
WaitUntilNavigation[] waitUntilNavigations = new WaitUntilNavigation[1]; waitUntilNavigations[0] = WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded; await page.GoToAsync(url,new NavigationOptions { WaitUntil = waitUntilNavigations });

await page.ClickAsync("a#empTable_next");
```

I'm sure I'm on the right page but I'm getting the following error.

```
PuppeteerSharp.SelectorException: No node found for selector: 
a#empTable_next
```

I need your help.

Comment: Please don't repeat the same thing twice to bypass the post filter. Instead, provide more details, like a complete, runnable script and the site you're working with so others can actually help. Probably, you need to wait for the selector to be present if it's added asynchronously. There's nothing wrong per se with the one line shown here. Also, the tag [tag:atag] isn't related to `<a>` tags as you think.

Comment: Thanks for your help and warnings.  I'm waiting for it to be fully loaded with these codes.     ` WaitUntilNavigation[] waitUntilNavigations = new WaitUntilNavigation[1];
            waitUntilNavigations[0] = WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded;
            await page.GoToAsync(url,new NavigationOptions
            {
                WaitUntil = waitUntilNavigations
            });`

Comment: Please [edit] the post with that info. Thanks.